# accessing kdb table from another namespace

Tags: kdb

struggling with accessing a table from a different namespace.
I have a function such as this:

```
\d .myns

myfunc:{[]
/\d / shows .myns when run manually (would love to have a ".Q.d" to run it programmatically) 
    if[not `mytable in tables `. ; .Q.l `$"/mypath/hdb" ];
    /if[not `mytable in tables `. ; '".myns.myfunc could not load mytable in `." ];
    `mytable in key `; / worth 0b
    `mytable in tables `.; / worth 1b
    `mytable in tables `.myns; / worth 0b
    meta mytable; / raise exception `mytable as it can't find mytable
    select from `..mytable where date = .z.d -1 / not sure if it's supposed to work but doesn't in any case
    meta `.[`mytable]; / not sure if it's supposed to work but doesn't in any case
    };
```

But if I go to the scratchpad and just run `meta mytable` then it runs without issue.
Would someone be able to explain how to access a hdb table from a function in a different namespace  please? I was unable to figure out the issue from the online doc...

**EDIT**

ok i figured out the problem.

```
if[not `mytable in tables `. ; .Q.l `$"/mypath/hdb" ];
```

my process was not "clean" as I had queried it from python.
From python, I am in the root namespace and .Q.l loads my table in the root namespace.
But when i run the code manually in the analyst I am in .myns
so having queried my process, the test mytable in tables `. is now 1b: the .Q.l is not run, and mytable resides in the rootnamespace.     Then i run the code manually` meta mytable` which actually queries .myns.mytable
so I amended the code this way:

```
if[not `mytable in tables system "d" ; .Q.l `$"/mypath/hdb" ];
```

this way when i query from outside it works, and when I run manually, system "d" is worth .myns and the .Q.l is ran and load the table in .myns.

This should work but this is not ideal: the table is going to be loaded once by namespace. Is there a way to have .Q.l loading the table in the rootnamespace? I've tried to play around but no success...
Also it does not work I get a **par** error when i run the code manually. querying from python works fine. and actually running manually *after* querying from python fixes the par error. To be continued...

Answer (score 1):

I've never used KX Analyst, can you not run code from the root namespace? Yes you should load the hdb into the root namespace and not `.myns`. The reason it works loading into `.myns` after python is because the python call will define some necessary globals in the root such as sym and date(if hdb is date partitioned). Something like this should load the hdb into the root namespace:

```
loadHdb:{
  ns:string system"d";
  system "d .";
  .Q.l `hdb;
  system "d ",ns};
```

Edit: this actually doesn't work when called remotely from a client

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for the help, again. yes i diged today and actually doing `"meta mytable"` i get an error like "..sym" which I interpret as sym missing from the root namespace (but it is present in .myns). As a solution I tried to do exactly what you posted. the problem is if I do `system "d .";` it does not set me in the root namespace. if i do `sytem "d ."; system "d";` I still get "`.myns". I am no fan of KX Analyst but I don't have an alternative really, I don't feel like coding in notepad and running in a command prompt... I would love to have something like RStudio but well...

Comment: Yeah in hindsight that code probably doesn't work as a remote call from KX analyst. I currently use qpad for running queries against q processes, it's free and runs in global namespace. http://www.qinsightpad.com/

Comment: Qpad does expire every 3 months which is annoying, you have to redownload it when this happens

Comment: I'll try that on monday. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a syntax error around .z.d -1, whitespace is important to note here. Currently .z.d -1 is attempting to index to -1 in .z.d but this is not a list.  The below changes to the select statement should allow the function to run:

```sql
select from `..mytable where date = .z.d - 1;
```

You can also use .Q.dd within the select statement. This is a useful function for joining symbols - see more info: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qdd-join-symbols

```sql
select from .Q.dd[`.;`t] where date = .z.d - 1;
```

For the first line of the function you could replace the \d with system"d". System allows programmatic use of [A-Z] for anything you want to send to the os. For example

```
system "ls"
system"p 1234"
```

Comment: nope. as per code sample the problem happens also with a simple meta mytable;  It seems but im not sure, that when I run things line by line in the analyst, i'm set automatically in .myns . system "d" is .myns and meta .Q.dd[`.;`mytable] doesn't find mytable. but `mytable in `. is 1b ... im lost...